# Applying set-theory to C++11 variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Say I have two variadic templates; `typename... T, typename... U`, how would I go about finding their;

1. Concatenation
2. Maximal common sub-sequence
3. Inverse of the maximal common sub-sequence

So from what I understand, the concatenation is simple; `(t..., u...)`, but what about finding the maximal common sub-sequence of the two? - is it even possible?

Comment: what if `T... = a, b`; `U... = b,a` ?

Comment: Union isn't that simple: you need to remove duplicates. Variadic templates do not define sets.

Comment: Could not imagine, where you may use it

Comment: What you have is not a union but rather a disjoint union. To make it a union you need to exclude duplicates.

Comment: You want to commpute these operations on the types, or on the values?

Comment: The first problem here is having two variadic parameters in the same declaration.  It can be done, but it's not trivial.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I've just realized that it's actually not union nor intersection I'm in need of; Given two variadic templates, what I'm in need of is their overlap; given `(int,int,char)` and `(int,char,int)`, I need `(int,char)`.

Comment: @aschepler: I've already got the two variadic parameters, so that problem is already solved.

Comment: So, you need the intersection of the type sets

Comment: @RiaD: Clearly I do not need union, and intersection, but rather concatenation and whatever intersection translates to in that sense.

Comment: @RiaD: The question is mostly due to curiousness, but if possible I could find ways to use it I'm sure.

Comment: Does order matter, or should `(int,int,char)` + `(char,int)` also produce `(int,char)`?

Comment: @aschepler: Order matters.

Comment: So you want maximal common subsequence.  Possibly doable, but yikes.

Comment: Also, a maximal common subsequence is not always unique.

Comment: @aschepler; Yes, that's what I want! - But how is it not always unique?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: `T...` is `A,B,C,D`.  `U...` is `C,D,A,B`.  Is the answer `A,B` or `C,D`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This is not really a question of getting people to write code for me, it's rather a question of whether it's possible.

Comment: @Skeen Please see the "Not Constructive" question closure reason text.

Comment: @aschepler: In what I imagine the answer should be either `A,B,C,D` or undefined. - But the issue of having non-unique solutions disappears if one sequence is a subset of the other doesn't it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Why shouldn't one be able to provide an answer that is supported by facts? - This is a question that can be answered, not something that is to be debated?

Comment: So now what you want is a maximal common subsequence?

Comment: Do you have some application of this stuff in mind?

Comment: @n.m.: No specific application, no, mostly experiments.

Comment: @AndyProwl: The solution you posted was just fine, to inspire me, I' ll start experimenting with it right away.

Comment: @Skeen: OK. I will try answering 2)

Comment: @AndyProwl: You dont have to, but if you feel like it alright, ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution that computes **set operations on pairs of tuple types**. I assume tuples can be used to hold the variable argument packs, so that once you have `Ts...` and `Us...`, you do:

```
typename tuple_intersect<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>>::type
```

And this gives you a tuple, where `Vs...` is the intersection of `Ts...` and `Us...`. If you need to extract `Vs...` as an argument pack again, just provide the tuple as the input of a function which accepts a `tuple<Ts...>`:

```
template<typename... Vs>
void func(std::tuple<Vs...>)
{
    // Here, you have Vs... (= Us... & Ts...) as an argument pack
}
```

---

**Framework**:

Here are some simple meta-functions which are common to all the main meta-functions below:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct is_member_of_type_seq { static const bool value = false; };

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct is_member_of_type_seq<T, U, Ts...>
{
    static const bool value = std::conditional<
        std::is_same<T, U>::value,
        std::true_type,
        is_member_of_type_seq<T, Ts...>
        >::type::value;
};

template<typename, typename>
struct append_to_type_seq { };

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct append_to_type_seq<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts..., T>;
};

template<typename, typename>
struct prepend_to_type_seq { };

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct prepend_to_type_seq<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
};
```

---

> 1 -  **Concatenation**

This one is pretty simple:

```
template<typename, typename>
struct concat_type_seq { };

template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat_type_seq<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts..., Us...>;
};
```

And some testing:

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        concat_type_seq<
            std::tuple<char, int, bool>,
            std::tuple<double, double, int>
            >::type,
        std::tuple<char, int, bool, double, double, int>
        >::value,
    "Error"
    );
```

---

> 2 - **Longest common subsequence**

This one is *slightly* more complicated:

```
namespace detail
{
    // Meta-function that returns, given two sequences S1 and S2, the longest
    // subsequence of S1 in S2 that starts with the first element of S1 and
    // begins at the first element of S2 (in other words, it returns the
    // subsequence S2[0]..S2[N] such that S1[i] = S2[i] for each 0 <= i <= N.
    template<typename, typename>
    struct match_seq_in_seq_from_start
    {
        using type = std::tuple<>;
    };

    template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
    struct match_seq_in_seq_from_start<std::tuple<T, Ts...>, std::tuple<U, Us...>>
    {
        using type = typename std::conditional<
            std::is_same<T, U>::value,
            typename prepend_to_type_seq<
                T,
                typename match_seq_in_seq_from_start<
                    std::tuple<Ts...>,
                    std::tuple<Us...>
                    >::type
                >::type,
            std::tuple<>
            >::type;
    };

    // Some testing...
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            match_seq_in_seq_from_start<
                std::tuple<int, double, char>,
                std::tuple<int, double, long>
                //         ^^^^^^^^^^^
                >::type,
            std::tuple<int, double>
            >::value,
        "Error!"
        );

    // Meta-function that returns the same as the meta-function above,
    // but starting from the first element of S2 which is identical to
    // the first element of S1.
    template<typename, typename>
    struct match_first_seq_in_seq
    {
        using type = std::tuple<>;
    };

    template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
    struct match_first_seq_in_seq<std::tuple<T, Ts...>, std::tuple<U, Us...>>
    {
        using type = typename std::conditional<
            std::is_same<T, U>::value,
            typename match_seq_in_seq_from_start<
                std::tuple<T, Ts...>,
                std::tuple<U, Us...>
                >::type,
            typename match_first_seq_in_seq<
                std::tuple<T, Ts...>,
                std::tuple<Us...>
                >::type
            >::type;
    };

    // Some testing...
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            match_first_seq_in_seq<
                std::tuple<int, double, char>,
                std::tuple<bool, char, int, double, long, int, double, char>
                //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
                >::type,
            std::tuple<int, double>
            >::value,
        "Error!"
        );

    // Meta-function that returns, given two sequences S1 and S2, the longest
    // subsequence of S1 in S2 that starts with the first element of S1.
    template<typename T, typename U>
    struct match_seq_in_seq
    {
        using type = std::tuple<>;
    };

    template<typename U, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
    struct match_seq_in_seq<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<U, Us...>>
    {
        using type1 = typename match_first_seq_in_seq<
            std::tuple<Ts...>,
            std::tuple<U, Us...>
            >::type;

        using type2 = typename match_seq_in_seq<
            std::tuple<Ts...>, 
            std::tuple<Us...>
            >::type;

        using type = typename std::conditional<
            (std::tuple_size<type1>::value > std::tuple_size<type2>::value),
            type1,
            type2
            >::type;
    };

    // Some testing...
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            match_seq_in_seq<
                std::tuple<int, double, char>,
                std::tuple<char, int, double, long, int, double, char>
                //                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                >::type,
            std::tuple<int, double, char>
            >::value,
        "Error!"
        );
}

// Meta-function that returns, given two sequences S1 and S2, the longest
// subsequence of S1 in S2 (longest common subsequence).
template<typename T, typename U>
struct max_common_subseq
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct max_common_subseq<std::tuple<T, Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>>
{
    using type1 = typename detail::match_seq_in_seq<
        std::tuple<T, Ts...>,
        std::tuple<Us...>
        >::type;

    using type2 = typename max_common_subseq<
        std::tuple<Ts...>,
        std::tuple<Us...>
        >::type;

    using type = typename std::conditional<
        (std::tuple_size<type1>::value > std::tuple_size<type2>::value),
        type1,
        type2
        >::type;
};
```

And some testing:

```
// Some testing...
static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        max_common_subseq<
            std::tuple<int, double, char>,
            std::tuple<char, int, char, double, char, long, int, bool, double>
            >::type,
        std::tuple<double, char>
        >::value,
    "Error!"
    );

// Some more testing...
static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        max_common_subseq<
            std::tuple<int, double, char, long, long, bool>,
            //                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            std::tuple<char, long, long, double, double, char>
            //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            >::type,
        std::tuple<char, long, long>
        >::value,
    "Error!"
    );
```

---

> 3 - **Inversion**

Here is a trait for inverting a type sequence (returns a tuple with inverted type list):

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct revert_type_seq
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct revert_type_seq<T, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename append_to_type_seq<
        T,
        typename revert_type_seq<Ts...>::type
        >::type;
};
```

And some testing:

```
// Some testing...
static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        revert_type_seq<char, int, bool>::type,
        std::tuple<bool, int, char>
        >::value,
    "Error"
    );
```

---

> 4 - **Intersection**

This one was not requested, but is provided as a bonus:

```
template<typename, typename>
struct intersect_type_seq
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct intersect_type_seq<std::tuple<T, Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>>
{
    using type = typename std::conditional<
        !is_member_of_type_seq<T, Us...>::value,
        typename intersect_type_seq<
            std::tuple<Ts...>,
            std::tuple<Us...>>
            ::type,
        typename prepend_to_type_seq<
            T,
            typename intersect_type_seq<
                std::tuple<Ts...>,
                std::tuple<Us...>
                >::type
            >::type
        >::type;
};
```

And some testing:

```
// Some testing...
static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        intersect_type_seq<
            std::tuple<char, int, bool, double>,
            std::tuple<bool, long, double, float>
            >::type,
        std::tuple<bool, double>
        >::value,
        "Error!"
        );
```

Comment: Lovely!  I'm sure that my solution can be built of this

Comment: @Skeen: I think I've answered 1) and 3) so far, plus intersection (I thought that was needed). I'll try to answer 2)

Comment: This is actually really impressive!

Comment: @Skeen: OK, it looks like the maximum common subsequence is going to get a lot more complicated. It certainly can be done, but I won't be able to try now. Will certainly get back to it if I have time, it's a good exercise anyway :)

Comment: Indeed, however I think I'll try something simpler like finding prefixes and sufixes.

Comment: It would actually be interesting and useful to find the difference between two variadic templates.

Comment: @Skeen: Added the longest common subsequence

Comment: I've just been attempting a bunch of similar things using `std::index_sequence` instead of doing any explicit recursion.  See [tuple_tools.h on github](https://github.com/d1manson/waveform_cpp/blob/60cb8df0d097ccc91732e1d68d62e63099f44e06/tuple_tools.h).